# Некорректное отображение при свайпинге в ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так. У меня есть GridView, который сеткой выводит картинки из ресурсов. Я их храню в массиве в главном активити вот таким образом:

```
public static   int[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.card1, R.drawable.card2,
            R.drawable.card3, R.drawable.card4, R.drawable.card5,
            R.drawable.card6, R.drawable.card7, R.drawable.card8,
            R.drawable.card9, R.drawable.card10, R.drawable.card11,
            R.drawable.card12, R.drawable.card13, R.drawable.card14,
            R.drawable.card15, R.drawable.card16, R.drawable.card17,
            R.drawable.card18, R.drawable.card19, R.drawable.card20,
            R.drawable.card21 };
```

По клику на картинку, я получаю её номер в массиве(номер правильный, я проверял логами), засовываю этот номер в Intent и открываю новое активити:

```
  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    FullImageActivity.class);
            // passing array index
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);
```

В новом активи, я получаю номер, инициализирую ViewPager, указываю ему адаптер и одним из параметров передаю этот самый position:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);
        adapter = new SlideImageAdapter(this, position);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Далее собственно и сама **проблема**: В адаптере я получаю нужную позицию, при клике по изображению  выводится правильное изображение, но при свайпинге влево-вправо изображение не меняется. Если же я пытаюсь получить изображение непосредственно из адаптера, то по клику на любое изображение всегда выводится первое в массиве, хотя в этом случае свайпинг работает правильно. Как правильнее реализовать мою задумку?  Вот сам адаптер:

```
public class SlideImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    int number;

    public SlideImageAdapter(Context mContext, int number){

        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.number = number;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return MainActivity.mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view==(LinearLayout)object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_view =  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);

        imageView.setImageResource(MainActivity.mThumbIds[position]);
        container.addView(item_view);

        return item_view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }
}
```

Comment: А можно еще добавить в вопрос разметку 'swipe_layout' и код обработчика клика на изображение.

Comment: А как в новом активити ViewPager будет что-то свапить, если вы передали ему только один position?

Answer (score 1):

У вас `int number` внутри адаптера не используется.

> Если же я пытаюсь получить изображение непосредственно из адаптера, то по клику на любое изображение всегда выводится первое в массиве, хотя в этом случае свайпинг работает правильно.

Именно по этому и выводится первое в массиве.
Нужно вызвать `viewPager.setCurrentItem(position)` после `setAdapter`